# Filter function in r

Tags: r

I am using a fast-food dataset where i need to filter out restaurant that has between 45 and 50 items. I am using the following code, but it is not exactly giving me the correct values

```
fastfood <- openintro::fastfood
head(fastfood)

U1<-fastfood %>%
filter(fastfood, item >=45 & item <=50)
```

Comment: What output is it giving you and why isn't it correct? If you are using ``dplyr::filter``, make sure you are using that rather than ``stats::filter``

Comment: Would U1<-subset(fastfood,item>=45 & item<=50) work?

Comment: This is only giving me 37 observations, It should be 165 observation

Comment: In the `filter` expression you need to reference the **column** not the dataframe!

Answer (score 0):

This is filtering out restaurants with `45<=number of items<=50` :

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(fastfood)[, N := .N, by = restaurant][(N<=45)|(N>=50)]
```

However in your case I can't see any restaurant with `45<=number of items<=50`